# Zend Session Namespace

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm having a bit of a collision with the naming of the `Zend_Session_Namespace` parameter.

What is the convention for the namespace other than "default"? Lets say i want to use it in the frontcontroller, should i name it `Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Controller');` because the `Zend_Auth` convention is `Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');`

Answer (score 2):

You should namespace it in a way you can remember it and where it makes sense. If you are storing e.g. user options for a guest, maybe his name and email address for comments, you should probably name the namespace something like "guest-data". There is no real convention for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution at Zend Framework reference guide
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html

It states that "Namespace names are restricted to character sequences represented as non-empty PHP strings that do not begin with an underscore ("_") character. 
Only core components included in Zend Framework should use namespace names starting with "Zend"."

Hope this helps you